Why ThreadX's entry function use ULONG as entry input instead of a void*?
UINT tx_thread_create(TX_THREAD *thread_ptr, CHAR *name_ptr, 
                      VOID (*entry_function)(ULONG), ULONG entry_input, 
                      VOID *stack_start, ULONG stack_size, UINT priority,
                      UINT preempt_threshold, ULONG time_slice, 
                      UINT auto_start)

Documentation:

If I need to pass more than one parameter to the entry_function I must necessarily use a void *, hence my question, why ThreadX uses a ULONG instead of a void * like FreeRTOS does?

Ask the authors. I guess when they started development they thought that the integer would be enough. Then they had to carry on

@0___________ I hope they have a more plausible explanation, I mean it cost nothing to use VOID *, like they did for the stack_start parameter.

ULONG is the argument to the thread entry function - the type of the pointer is VOID (*entry_function)(ULONG).

@500-InternalServerError he is asking why it is ULONG and not void *. It is obvious that both have to to have the same type :)

@500-InternalServerError I know that, my question is why use a ULONG instead of a void *?
I would expect something like that UINT tx_thread_create(TX_THREAD *thread_ptr, CHAR *name_ptr, VOID (*entry_function)(VOID *), VOID *entry_input, VOID *stack_start, ULONG stack_size, UINT priority, UINT preempt_threshold, ULONG time_slice, UINT auto_start)

What the argument to the thread start point is, is app-specific - it's not always a pointer, although I admit that it often is. Why is this a big deal to you?

Because that's what whomever wrote that library felt was the appropriate type.

@500-InternalServerError I need to write a function to create a thread that is OS agnostic, so that it can work with ThreadX, FreeRTOS, Linux pthread and so on, since I need to pass a parameter to the entry function I noticed this difference between FreeRTOS and ThreadX

ULONG has an advantage over void *: all bit combinations of an integer type are valid.  Not so with pointers.

I would guess it is due to the history. ThreadX is from the 1990ies, i.e. before C99 introduced types like uintptr_t and similar. And at some time where 64bit pointers weren't really a thing in the vast mayority of CPUs. They might have assumed that a long integer type would be large enough to hold a pointer anyways.

@Gerhardh This explanation doesn't convince me, the void * type has been around since C was born, I found references in the "The C Programming Language" book (1978), so I don't see why the initial developers decided to assume that a unsigned int was large enough to hold a pointer, when void * already existed, especially because with the next parameter stack_start they used the VOID * type. I'm sure they had their reasons, but I'm curious to understand what they might be.

@chux-ReinstateMonica I don't understand what you mean, could you please explain better?

Code could pass 0x76544321 as a long, but (void*)0x76544321 may be an invalid address that cannot exist.

X-Y problem.  Why not ask directly how to pass a structure to a thread function?

"I don't see why the initial developers decided to assume that a unsigned int was large enough to hold a pointer" - they didn't; they chose unsigned long (presumably what ULONG is) at the time the largest integer type available in C and large enough to hold a pointer on all platforms ThreadX is implemented for.

@Clifford I think this is the most plausible explanation, ULONG was the widest type in existence capable of holing a void * and an unsigned long int. However if this was their goal, I would have opted for a #define allowing the user to declare the type of entry_input, which would have allowed the use of types wider (e.g. typedef struct {...}) or narrower (e.g. char) than ULONG.

@ParminderSingh - there are many design decisions one might make differently, that does not make it "wrong".  To support your proposal tx_thread_create would require a void* entry_input and perhaps a size_t entry_input_size parameter.  The scheduler has to start the thread and pass the argument, so you cannot have arbitrarily sized objects as parameters because the kernel would not know how to call it.

@Clifford When I said "I would have opted for a #define" - I meant a ThreadX option where user can define the entry_input parameter type, so replacing tx_thread_create(... ULONG entry_input ...) with tx_thread_create(... ENTRY_TYPE entry_input ...), where ENTRY_TYPE can be anything user-defined (e.g. typedef struct {...}, char, ULONG, void *, etc...)

@ParminderSingh  I know what you meant and it won't work without recompilation of the kernel.  Also you would then be requiring all threads to take that parameter.

From comments you clearly already know how to work around the problem making this simply question of opinion since the documentation itself offers no justification.  As such this question is off-topic and should be closed.  ThreadX predates FreeRTOS, why would you expect the authors to make the same design decisions? FreeRTOS is hardly the arbiter of good design, it is full of "interesting" design decisions. All RTOS differ - VxWorks  taskSpawn for example takes ten int arguments passed to the thread function. VxWorks predates ThreadX even.
